# How to compile a .pyx file of a package after making changes?

Tags: python, package, cython

I did some changes to a .pyx file of a python package called pomegranate, but now I don't know how to actually make my code run (after saving the changes and running the program my changes don't occur). I think that I need to compile the .pyx file or maybe the whole package? How to do this?

Comment: Is this package `pomegranate` downloadable from the net? If yes, best to post the link in your question.

Comment: @rnso , here is the link https://github.com/jmschrei/pomegranate :)

Answer (score 0):

Instructions are given on the [website](https://github.com/jmschrei/pomegranate).

Links to detailed instructions for each model are also given on the page. For example, for Probability Distributions, you can go [here](https://pomegranate.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Distributions.html). Some code from this page are:

```
from pomegranate import *
a = NormalDistribution(5, 2)

b = NormalDistribution.from_samples([3, 4, 5, 6, 7])

b = NormalDistribution.from_samples([3, 4, 5, 6, 7], weights=[0.5, 1, 1.5, 1, 0.5])

>>> a = NormalDistribution(5, 2)
>>> a.log_probability(8)
-2.737085713764219
>>> a.probability(8)
0.064758797832971712
>>> b = NormalDistribution.from_samples([3, 4, 5, 6, 7], weights=[0.5, 1, 1.5, 1, 0.5])
>>> b.log_probability(8)
-4.437779569430167

d = NormalDistribution(5, 2)
d.fit([1, 5, 7, 3, 2, 4, 3, 5, 7, 8, 2, 4, 6, 7, 2, 4, 5, 1, 3, 2, 1])
d
{
    "frozen" :false,
    "class" :"Distribution",
    "parameters" :[
        3.9047619047619047,
        2.13596776114341
    ],
    "name" :"NormalDistribution"
}
```

Comment: My question is: after downloading and installing the package, I want to change some of the pyx files. I don't know, however, how to compile them after applying my changes locally.

Comment: This page may be of help: https://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/quickstart/build.html